# JavaScript/jQuery - Delay Loading Page When Clicking Hyperlinks at Mobile Resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using a [CSS hover effect](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/06/19/ideas-for-subtle-hover-effects/) that I found on Codrops in my web portfolio's [work page](https://www.tylerfuller.me/work). At mobile resolutions, the elements' animation is activated by clicking the hyperlinked image, but the transition doesn't always have time to complete before loading the next page.

Is there a way to utilize JavaScript/jQuery to delay the loading of a page/website at mobile resolutions?

### Update:

I've combined Yaseen Ahmed's solution below with a jQuery-based [StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36607830/how-to-delay-a-hyperlink-until-a-css-animation-ends) that I finally ran across for a perfect solution to my problems.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.delay').click(function(e) {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $a = $(this).addClass('clicked');

      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.assign($a.attr('href'));
      }, 2500);
    } else {
      window.location.assign($a.attr('href'));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
section {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}

figure {
  cursor: pointer;
}

figure.apollo {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background: #c3589e;
}

figure.apollo img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

figure.apollo figcaption {
  padding: 2rem;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

figure.apollo figcaption::before,
figure.apollo figcaption::after {
  pointer-events: none;
}

figure.apollo figcaption,
figure.apollo figcaption>a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: none;
}

figure.apollo figcaption>a {
  z-index: 5;
  white-space: nowrap;
  span {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

figure.apollo img {
  opacity: 0.95;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
}

figure.apollo figcaption::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  content: '';
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform: scale3d(2.2, 1.4, 1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg) translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}

figure.apollo figcaption p span {
  margin: .25rem 0;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

figure.apollo:hover img {
  opacity: 0.6;
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

figure.apollo:hover figcaption::before {
  transform: scale3d(2.2, 1.4, 1) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg) translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <section>
    <p>Make sure you shrink your viewport width to less than 768px before testing the link delay.</p>

    <figure class="apollo">
      <img src="https://www.tylerfuller.me/assets/images/sakura.jpg" alt="Cherry Blossoms" />

      <figcaption>
        <p><span>This is a link to the</span><br />
          <span>pure CSS Sakura</span><br />
          <span>theme / framework.</span></p>

        <a class="delay" href="https://oxal.org/projects/sakura/"></a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: hope the answer will help you if didn't let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to create the java script function in your project see in code.

**your hyper link**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="loadpage()"></a>
```

**java script function**

```
function loadpage() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
      setTimeout(function(){
        location.href="your_url";
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      location.href="your_url";
    }
  }
```

What will this function do when your screen width is less then 768 it will load url after one second and if grater then it will load url without delay.

**Note :**  When you resize the screen width must reload the page.

Comment: I've updated my original question to include a jQuery-based solution that I created thanks to your help and another stackoverflow answer.